# $L^1$ functions approximated by non-decreasing continuous sequences

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Actually the origin problem is:

Suppose $f \in L^1([0,1])$, prove that there are two non-decreasing sequences of continuous functions ${g_k},{h_k}$ which are $a.e.$ bounded, and $$f(x)=\lim_{k \to \infty}g_k(x)-\lim_{k \to \infty}h_k(x)$$

Normally we write $f=f^+-f^-$ and first find a non-decreasing sequences of continuous functions ${g_k}$ such that $$\lim_{k \to \infty}g_k=f^+$$, but I failed for the non-decreasing condition's annoying.

Also I have tried to find a kernel whose convolution with $f$ converges to $f$ in the $L^1$ form. And then it converges to $f$ in measure, hence there exists a sub-sequences converges to $f$ $a.e. x \in [0,1]$. But at last I find it doesn't satisfied the non-decreasing condition.

So I sincerely need you help, any attempts would be appreciated.

Comment: I'll start with a sequence of truncation function $f^{+}_k=f^{+}$ if $f^{+}\leq k$ otherwise 0, each can be approximated by a continuous function(cont. function dense in $L^1([0,1])$), get a seq. converge in measure, and take convergence(a.e.) subsequence. There is still a little bit argument to be made why continuous functions can be picked to be non-decreasing.

Comment: @frank000 I think trying to find kernels is a feasible way, the non-decreasing continuous sequences may be constructed by the convolution of some kernel and $f^+$.